# Same code gives different animation in different pens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I copied the code from http://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/DAbuf offline but my animation is different from the one in pen? After that I copied the code from original pen to my pen exactly but still I got different animation? Whats going on?

Here is the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.min.js"></script>
<body>
<figure>
<button>Recommend</button>
<div class="shadow"></div>
</figure>
<script>
$("button").mousedown(function(){
$(this).html("Recommended").velocity({
backgroundColorRed : "0",
translateY: "-1.5rem",
rotateZ: "-10deg"
}, 100, "easeOutBounce").velocity({
rotateZ: "8deg",
}, 150).velocity({
translateY: "0",
rotateZ: "0"
}, 600, "easeOutBounce");

$("+ .shadow", this).velocity({
scale: "1.3",
opacity: "1"
}, 150).velocity("reverse", 600, "easeOutBounce");
});
</script>
```

Even if I replace easeOutBounce with anyfh or any meningless value I get same animation?

```
$("+ .shadow", this).velocity({
scale: "1.3",
opacity: "1"
}, 150).velocity("reverse", 600, "anyfh");
```

Comment: For me copying works without problems. Maybe you have some other problem locally? You are also not loading the exact same library versions codepen uses. And can you supply your copied pen of which you said that it also doesn't work?

Comment: What Jey said - pretty sure you are not using the exact same versions of jQuery and velocity.js. Could be the culprit.

Comment: Is there any way to know which version they are using?